# error jdeveloper adf deployment

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am developing an application on jdeveloper. I realized in a first time a project I made the deployment and I integrated it in another application and it works very well. Or when I make changes on the first project and I do another deployment to see the changes on the main application it shows me this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on how you integrated the two? Did you just created a jar from the first project and used it as a library in the second?